# The steps to get $\beta$ in Least Square Estimation, why $x_i$ was removed?

Tags: statistics, regression, least-squares

Please see the following steps

Get $\beta$ in Least Square Estimation:

[image]

Comment: add the reference, https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/soc/economics/staff/vetroeger/teaching/po906_week567.pdf

Answer (score 1):

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n y_i-\bar{y}+\hat{\beta}(\bar{x}-x_i) =0 \implies \sum\limits_{i=1}^n (y_i-\bar{y}) = - \hat{\beta}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(\bar{x}-x_i)  \implies  \hat{\beta} = \dfrac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (y_i-\bar{y}) }{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x})  }$ looks a strange thing to say this way  since I would have thought $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (y_i-\bar{y})=0$ and $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar{x})=0$ by the definition of $\bar{y}$ and $\bar{x}$.  Saying $\hat{\beta} =\frac00$ would not be helpful.

That being said, I would have thought you can say $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n y_i-\bar{y}+B(\bar{x}-x_i) =0$ was obviously true for any $B$ and this implies $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n y_i-\bar{y}+\hat{\beta}(\bar{x}-x_i) =0$ and so $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \left(y_i-\bar{y}+\hat{\beta}(\bar{x}-x_i)\right)\bar{x} =0$.  Subtract that from the earlier $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \left(y_i-\bar{y}+\hat{\beta}\bar{x}-\hat{\beta}x_i\right)x_i =0$ and you can get the final line and the desired conclusion.

Comment: thanks. Do you mean $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \left(y_i-\bar{y}+\hat{\beta}\bar{x}-\hat{\beta}x_i\right)x_i  -  \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \left(y_i-\bar{y}+\hat{\beta}(\bar{x}-x_i)\right)\bar{x} $? I think they are not equal, right?

Comment: @novice The first sum is $0$ from your first red box.  The second sum is zero because both  $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (y_i-\bar{y})=0$ and $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar{x})=0$ from the definition of average and so is a linear combination of them.  So they are equal

Comment: thanks, I understand what you mean now. The final result can be achived as you mentioned.